# PrivCopyFileExW Bug in Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-7

I am issuing many parallel robocopy calls to copy files from one network share into one directory. Since the files are read only I tell robocopy to strip off the read only attribute in the target directory via /A-:R. It seems that on some many core machine (12 or more) the target directory! gets locked for up to 16s.

This problem does surface when concurrent MSBuild tasks are running and the CopyFile task is executed on read only files. It does also happen when robocopy is executed to download dependencies for a TFS build in parallel from a network share. Since all these issues point to kernel32 CopyFile (or its private implementation) I suspect that the problem is related to how Windows does copy files.

This does not seem to be a general issue in the kernel since the temp folder live from the fact that concurrent access to a directory must be possible. But the user mode implementation inside kernel32.dll of CopyFile seems to be flawed.

**Update 2**
With the repro below this does happen no matter if the file is read only or not.

**Update 3**
This repro does also show the same issue on Windows 8.

The procmon stack traces did show that the magic happens in kernel32.dll inside
PrivCopyFileExW which seems to be rather undocumented. There an [IRP_MJ_CREATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff548630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call is issued to open the directory and a little later the directory is closed. This seems to be the root cause of the race condition when many parallel robocopy processes try to copy files into one directory.

Here is some [procmon](http://forum.sysinternals.com/how-can-user-mode-app-call-irp-mj-create_topic27676.html) output how this problem feels like.

Why on earth does PrivCopyFileExW manage to lock the directory? A file system should be able support copying files into one directory. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 and some latest multi cores machines with RAID arrays, SSDs and such stuff.

This seems to be related to reported problems with [CopyFile in kernel32.dll](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vcgeneral/thread/54bef96f-3ca1-4dd7-a621-da2fa8d8b35b) which have not be solved until today. I can rule out virus scanners because this does also happen at machines which have none installed.

**Update 1**

It seems that another robocopy process does try to copy a file to the destination directory which opens the directory

```
Date & Time:    20.03.2012 08:30:06
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  CreateFile
Result: SUCCESS
Path:   C:\temp\dest
TID:    11672
Duration:   0.0000150
Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Write Data/Add File, Write EA, Read Attributes, Write Attributes, Delete, Synchronize
Disposition:    OpenIf
Options:    Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open For Backup
Attributes: D
ShareMode:  None  <---- No sharing
AllocationSize: 0
OpenResult: Opened

0   fltmgr.sys  FltpPerformPreCallbacks + 0x2f7 0xfffff88001045027  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
1   fltmgr.sys  FltpPassThroughInternal + 0x4a  0xfffff880010478ca  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
2   fltmgr.sys  FltpCreate + 0x293  0xfffff880010652a3  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
3   ntoskrnl.exe    IopParseDevice + 0x5a7  0xfffff800031cb537  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
4   ntoskrnl.exe    ObpLookupObjectName + 0x585 0xfffff800031c1ba4  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
5   ntoskrnl.exe    ObOpenObjectByName + 0x1cd  0xfffff800031c6b7d  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
6   ntoskrnl.exe    IopCreateFile + 0x2b7   0xfffff800031cd647  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
7   ntoskrnl.exe    NtCreateFile + 0x78 0xfffff800031d7398  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
8   ntoskrnl.exe    KiSystemServiceCopyEnd + 0x13   0xfffff80002eca813  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
9   ntdll.dll   NtCreateFile + 0xa  0x7718fc0a  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
10  kernel32.dll    BaseCopyStream + 0x11a9 0x77034b89  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
11  kernel32.dll    BasepCopyFileExW + 0x545    0x77033d85  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
12  kernel32.dll    PrivCopyFileExW + 0xb6  0x770b5296  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
13  Robocopy.exe    CZDir::CopyData + 0xb5  0xff8623a9  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
14  Robocopy.exe    RoboCopyDir + 0xe4  0xff85af00  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
15  Robocopy.exe    Walk + 0x12a    0xff85c6b6  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
16  Robocopy.exe    wmain + 0x4f4   0xff85de78  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
17  Robocopy.exe    operator+ + 0x19b   0xff867be5  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
18  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd   0x7703f33d  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
19  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1d   0x77172ca1  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
```

The other robocopy wants to check if the file already exists and calls FindFirstFile which lead to opening the directory as well with full sharing.

```
Date & Time:    20.03.2012 08:30:06
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  CreateFile
Result: SHARING VIOLATION
Path:   C:\temp\dest
TID:    8280
Duration:   0.0000099
Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  Read, Write, Delete <----- Full sharing
AllocationSize: n/a

0   fltmgr.sys  FltpPerformPreCallbacks + 0x2f7 0xfffff88001045027  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
1   fltmgr.sys  FltpPassThroughInternal + 0x4a  0xfffff880010478ca  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
2   fltmgr.sys  FltpCreate + 0x293  0xfffff880010652a3  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\fltmgr.sys
3   ntoskrnl.exe    IopParseDevice + 0x5a7  0xfffff800031cb537  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
4   ntoskrnl.exe    ObpLookupObjectName + 0x585 0xfffff800031c1ba4  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
5   ntoskrnl.exe    ObOpenObjectByName + 0x1cd  0xfffff800031c6b7d  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
6   ntoskrnl.exe    IopCreateFile + 0x2b7   0xfffff800031cd647  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
7   ntoskrnl.exe    NtOpenFile + 0x58   0xfffff800031e64a8  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
8   ntoskrnl.exe    KiSystemServiceCopyEnd + 0x13   0xfffff80002eca813  C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
9   ntdll.dll   NtOpenFile + 0xa    0x7718f9ea  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
10  KernelBase.dll  FindFirstFileExW + 0x1ee    0x7fefd3a560e   C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
11  KernelBase.dll  FindFirstFileW + 0x1c   0x7fefd3a58dc   C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll
12  Robocopy.exe    CZDir::Exists + 0xf7    0xff861bb7  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
13  Robocopy.exe    RoboCopyDir + 0x58  0xff85ae74  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
14  Robocopy.exe    Walk + 0x12a    0xff85c6b6  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
15  Robocopy.exe    wmain + 0x4f4   0xff85de78  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
16  Robocopy.exe    operator+ + 0x19b   0xff867be5  C:\Windows\System32\Robocopy.exe
17  kernel32.dll    BaseThreadInitThunk + 0xd   0x7703f33d  C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
18  ntdll.dll   RtlUserThreadStart + 0x1d   0x77172ca1  C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll
```

I can repro this easily on Windows 7 as well. You only need to copy read only files from two parallel robocopy calls into the same directory in a loop and wait until it happens (ca. 30s).

```
for /L %i in (1,1,1000) do robocopy /E /XO /COPY:DAT /A-:R C:\ReadOnlySource1  c:\temp\dest
for /L %i in (1,1,1000) do robocopy /E /XO /COPY:DAT /A-:R C:\ReadOnlySource2  c:\temp\dest
```

You can put only one read only file into the source directories to get a fast copy and many concurrent directory accesses. Is this a known limitation of Windows to not allow accessing a directory while a file is copied to it?

My uneducated opinion is that this is a bug and it can get quite nasty when you want concurrent access to files in a reliable manner.

Comment: Yeah, this got borken around Vista SP1 where they made some heavy changes to CopyFile().  It got a lot worse in Win7, I can rarely mass copy files with my file manager without running into it.  Luckily it has a retry feature which always works.  Nothing simple to fix I'm sure, no way that Microsoft doesn't already know about it.  Probably has something to do with tunneling.  You'll need to ask at superuser.com, probably at MS Support to get a workaround.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/02/04/2826167.aspx

Comment: I have opened a support request at MS. We will see if it gets higher prio if we add some business case to the request which shows that this issue really hurts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like we are getting a fix from MS for this issue finally. They have found and understood the issue. But it will take some time until the fix is officially prepared. Currently it will be only fixed for Windows 7.